# rxjs pipes: Argument of type Observable not assignable to parameter

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I'm new to rxjs and pipes - and pulling my hair out trying to understand why I'm getting this typescript error: "Argument of type Observable not assignable to parameter OperatorFunction". Could someone please explain this to me?

The intent is to ask for "Hello", but have the data replaced by "Bye" as the data gets piped.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHello()
      .pipe(this.getBye())
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
  getHello() {
    return of("Hello")
  }
  getBye() {
    return of ("Bye")
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect from this line `.pipe(this.getBye())`? It looks unlogical, and that is also the source of error

Comment: `this.getHello().pipe(_ => this.getBye())`

Comment: Did one of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map as Pipeable Operator:

```
this.getHello()
  .pipe(map((data) => { return this.getBye() }))
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
getHello() {
  return of("Hello");
}
getBye() {
  return of("Bye");
}
```

Links to check pipeable oprators in detail:
https://angular.io/guide/rx-library
https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Answer (score 1):

The pipe method receives an OperatorFunction but you are giving it your getBye() method which returns an Observable. You have to pass an OperatorFunction, "map" for example:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getHello()
    .pipe(map(_ => this.getBye()))
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}

getHello(): Observable<string> {
  return of('Hello');
}

getBye(): string {
  return 'Bye';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your own operator you have to wrap a function inside a function. The inner function is called when a new event is set onto the stream. At the same time you'll have access to the stream itself (`sourceStream`).

See the Stackblitz for a working example.

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.getHello()
          .pipe(this.getBye())
          .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
      }

      getHello() {
        return of("Hello")
      }

      getBye() {
        return (sourceSteam: any) => of("Bye")
      }
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-stackoverflow-52413693?file=index.ts